# Unique entries for normal entries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to MySQL, and I have two columns. My desired table is the following:

```
Column 1   Column 2
--------   --------
A          1
A          2
A          3
A          4
B          1
B          2
B          3
B          4
```

The problem I face, is for every row which has a value of A in column 1, column 2 must be unique, as seen above. However duplicates in Column 2 are allowed aslong as the corresponding Column 1 value is different from that of other entries?

I'm really sorry for the bad, wording, I'm just not sure how to ask the darn question.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Remove duplicates?  Add a constraint to prevent duplicates?  Query distinct values?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want Column 2 to be semi-unique? So all values in column 2 with A in Column 1 must be unique, however if column 1 has a B in it, it can be the same as the others but still unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DDL command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-data-definition.html) to add a unique constraint on multiple columns:

```
ALTER TABLE      `table_name` 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`column1`, `column2`);
```

Comment: I don't want both columns unique, I want Column 2 values under A to be unique. The table I have in my question is my desired table.

Comment: @DraganMarjanovic This command will make them unique together, not separately. Then you can enter these couples `(A, 1), (A, 2), (B, 1)` etc. But you can't enter `(A, 2)` (for instance) twice

Comment: Ah, Thank-You very much, sorry for the hassle, I will try improve the question for other users. =)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the `Column1` and `Column2` both unique :

```
alter table YOUR_TABLE add unique index(Column1, Column2);
```